# Revolution Slider Custom Cursor Width Issue

Tags: html, wordpress, css, revolution-slider

the slider I'm trying to build is something like this :

[marcusbredt.de](http://marcusbredt.de/)

The wordpress theme I'm working on is using revolution slider. The html and css is :

```css
#content .tparrows,
#content .hesperiden.tparrows {
 background: transparent;
 width: 44px;
 height: inherit;
 border-radius: 0;
 top: 50% !important;
 -webkit-transition: background linear .1s, color linear .1s, box-shadow linear .1s;
 -moz-transition: background linear .1s, color linear .1s, box-shadow linear .1s;
 -o-transition: background linear .1s, color linear .1s, box-shadow linear .1s;
 transition: background linear .1s, color linear .1s, box-shadow linear .1s;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tp-leftarrow tparrows hesperiden  noSwipe" style="top: 50%; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 250, -145); left: 0px;"></div>

<div class="tp-rightarrow tparrows hesperiden  noSwipe" style="top: 50%; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -344, -145); left: 100%;"></div>
```

Originally width and height was 44px I want to click and change slides everywhere I click the mouse. When I change the height to inherit works fine, cant find what to do with the width. If I gave a px value works fine in one screen resulution, doesnt work in the next. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS code:

```
.hesperiden.tparrows {
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}
```